# WPF/C# Link Two Variables together

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, ref

I currently have a simple WPF application, in the MainWindow I will have a variable (In this case the variable is a class that holds data). Then I have a User Control which has the same variable.
Currently, I'm passing the variable with the ref keyword and it works perfectly fine, however, is this save/good practice? Is there a better way of linking this two variables together?

I am aware of the existence of DependencyProperty, however, I could not get it to work.

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TestClassWithInfo m_SelectedInfo;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_SelectedInfo = new DrawingInformation();
        TestGridUC mp = new TestGridUC(ref m_SelectedInfo);
        TestCanvas.Childrens.Add(mp);
    }
}
```

TestGridUI:

```
public partial class TestGridUC : UserControl {
        private TestClassWithInfo m_SelectedInfo;

        public TestGridUC (ref TestClassWithInfo e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_SelectedInfo = e;
        }
}
```

TestClassWithInfo:

```
public class TestClassWithInfo 
{
    public Image imageTest;
    public int intTest;


    public TestClassWithInfo ()
    {
        m_img = null;
        m_layer = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, the `ref` keyword is pointless here, it does nothing. Besides that, you're passing `null` to the TestGridUC constructor, because you're assigning a value to m_SelectedInfo only after the constructor is called. Continue your research on dependency properties. Declare one in the UserControl class, then bind it to a property of your MainWindow (or better to a property of a view model object, which is assigned to the DataContext of the MainWindow). But first, read about data binding and MVVM in WPF.

Comment: Ok thanks, the null ref was actually a typing mistake when typing out the question, I first created the instance then passing the reference to it.

Comment: You're the engineer, be a rebel, but since you're asking... this is definitely not the best way.  Someone marked down the answer below but I'm marking it back up because if you're interested in using DependencyProperties (which is great) then I suggest taking the short time to learn it as suggested.  If not there are better ways so we can talk more about that if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware of the existence of DependencyProperty, however, I could not get it to work.

A dependency property really is the way to go about it though:

```
public partial class TestGridUC : UserControl
{
    public TestGridUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TestClassWithInfo Info 
    {
        get { return (TestClassWithInfo)GetValue(InfoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InfoProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Info", typeof(TestClassWithInfo), typeof(TestGridUC),
            new PropertyMetadata(null /*or initialize to a default of new TestClassWithInfo()*/ ));
}
```

Now you can bind to that property from the xaml in your MainWindow:

```
    <local:TestGridUC
        Info="{Binding Info}"></local:TestGridUC>
```

If you need help with that part, as pr177 answered there are many tutorials on getting started with WPF with the MVVM pattern.  The basics here would involve a view model object that contains a `TestClassWithInfo` public property that you bind to.

Comment: Thanks, After some research and reading the links from pr177. I got the two values to bind correctly. However, in the xaml the binding actually ended up looking `<local:TestGridUC Info="{Binding m_SelectedInfo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"></local:TestGridUC>` without the RelativeSource it would now work!

Comment: @peti446 Yeah a relative binding will work if you aren't using a ViewModel for your main window.  When the project starts to get complex you will want to move code that holds info objects like you made to ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) Pattern

There are many tutorials & introductions like that:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ivo_manolov/2012/03/17/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-applications-general-introduction/

or

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx